# Flutter wait til AwesomeDialog Dismiss

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dialog, synchronization, alert

I'm using AwesomeDialog in my Flutter project.
When this AwesomeDialog show, I want to stop next line execution until AwesomeDialog dismisses.

This is my code for AwesomeDialog Show

```
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Page(),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            AwesomeDialog(
              context: context,
              dialogType: DialogType.INFO,
              animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
              title: 'Register Status',
              desc: "Register Successfull",
              btnOkOnPress: () {
                print("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
              },
              width: 400,
            )..show();
            print("cccccccccccccccccccc");
          },
          child: Text("Show Dialog"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Debug Console :

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
cccccccccccccccccccc
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

I dont want print ccccccc until my Alert dismisses.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `await` keyword to stop the execution until the `Future` is resolved:

```
await AwesomeDialog(
 context: context,
 dialogType: DialogType.INFO,
 animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
 title: 'Register Status',
 desc: "Register Successfull",
 btnOkOnPress: () {
  print("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
 },
 width: 400,
 )..show();
```

In order to do so, we need to declare the `onPressed()` function as `async`:

```
onPressed: () async {
 print('aaa');  
 await AwesomeDialog(
  context: context,
  dialogType: DialogType.INFO,
  animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
  title: 'Register Status',
  desc: "Register Successfull",
  btnOkOnPress: () {
   print("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
  },
  width: 400,
  )..show();
  print('cccc');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Page(),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            AwesomeDialog(
              context: context,
              dialogType: DialogType.INFO,
              animType: AnimType.BOTTOMSLIDE,
              title: 'Register Status',
              desc: "Register Successfull",
              btnOkOnPress: () {
                print("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
              },
              width: 400,
            )..show().then((value) {
              print("cccccccccccccccccccc");
            });
          },
          child: Text("Show Dialog"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```